# Target route while using angular routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying to integrate angular routing with and existing app.
The webapp uses angular already but does not use routing per se.

I was able to manually integrate routing and my routing js looks like following

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/list1.jsp', {
        templateUrl: '/mycontext/templates/list1.jsp',
      }).
      when('/list2.jsp', {
        templateUrl: '/mycontext/templates/list2.jsp',
      }).
      otherwise({

      });
  }]);
```

After using routing for couple of files I found a common pattern, my #path was very similar to the path of the template. Thus I was wondering if there is any way to get the next url in the route itself so that I can dynamically create a fallback. For example

```
 otherwise({
            nextURL = $nxtURL;
            redirectTo:  '/mycontext/templates/'+nextURL;
          });
```

Comment: Just passing though and i would recommend since you're integrating routing to use ui-router instead of native ng-router (ui-router is more flexible). To focus more on your question, i didn't exactly understand what you want to do. You could try to use route parameters maybe ? ('/:listname' with as template '/mycontext/templates/'+listname) or something like this ?

Comment: @Okazari I am just trying to create a fall back. Currently the app has couple of hundred of screens, each one of them may have regular links pointing to other web pages and if a developer forgets to prepend a hash to it that link breaks. I am trying to dynamically retrieve what link was clicked on and insert the same web page as template

Comment: Could you give some examples of how final links and broken links looks ?

Comment: @Okazari the only difference between working and non working link would  be that non working link may not have a route defined in the routing file. So when it goes into otherwise clause I just want to check what link was clicked on and dynamically inject the template.